# ANDROID card expands to a form layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-cardview

Below image is the representation of  my question.

[image]

Pic 1 is the first activity which is having a text-view. If clicks the text view it should expands to the pic 2 to fill some details.

My question is how can i achieve this ? Is there is any component for this in android . I have googled it this but i am not able to find the solution for this ?

Pic 2 :-  user enter some data in the text box or drop-down, The the user submit  it . So i have take him to the first pic.

Any idea ? by using the card view how can i do ?

Below is the layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="THis is a first fragment layout"
        />
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view1"
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:longClickable="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="4dp"
        card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        card_view:contentPadding="10dp"
        >

        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/info_text"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#0000" 
                android:text="MY TEXT"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                />

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Put all in one layout and set the components of the right pic to Visible GONE. Change visibility if the textview is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use Scene animation, follow the tutorial

https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/building-animations-android-transition-framework-part-1/

you can see the similar use case in the GIF attached in the tutorial